# Extract just the strings from an array_column array return

Tags: php, arrays

I've got told many times, if there is a new question even on the same code to just create a new thread so here I am. Thanks to the guys for helping me with the previous question.

I have the following code:

```
/* Return an array of _octopus_ids */
$offices = array_map(
    function($post) {
        return array(
            'id' => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true),
        );
    },
    $query->posts
);

/* Dump out all the multi-dimensional arrays */
var_dump($offices);

$test = array_column($offices, 'id');
var_dump($test);
```

`var_dump($offices)` dumps the following:

> ```
> array (size=10)
>   0 => 
>     array (size=1)
>       'id' => string '1382' (length=4)
>   1 => 
>     array (size=1)
>       'id' => string '1330' (length=4)
> ```

`var_dump($test)` dumps the following:

> ```
> array (size=10)
>   0 => string '1382' (length=4)
>   1 => string '1330' (length=4)
> ```

**Problem**:

How can I use the following code:

`$results = $octopus->get_all('employees/' . $test;` which results in an `Notice: Array to string conversion` error.

I want to be able to make a results call such as this `$results = $octopus->get_all('employees/1382');` - So I want just the numeric string of $test to be appended to the end of employees/

If I hardcode the 1382 after employees/, I get the following result:

```php
object(stdClass)[1325]
  public 'id' => int 1382
```

What's the proper way to array of strings into just strings?